# Can one decide a holomorphic function given its countable zeros?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose that f is holomorphic on unit disk D and we know that f has countably many zeros at $t_k$’s where $k=0,1,2,\ldots$. Then can we necessarily write $f(z)=g(z)\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}z-t_k$ where $g$ is a holomorphic function?

Comment: Cf. the Weierstrass factorization theorem.

Comment: It's possible, but it's not _that_ simple. Specifically, that product doesn't converge nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Never.  The infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty (z - t_k)$ can't converge to a nonzero value if infinitely many $|z-t_k|$ are bounded away from $1$.

Comment: In that case, what can we tell from the zeros then?

Comment: You might look at [Blaschke products](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Blaschke_product)

Comment: Many thanks! I really appreciate it